# java JFrame not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a chess game but nothing shows up. Please help.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of formatting your code to make it more readable. Tip: tabs don't work up in code blocks. You have to use spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added to what @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels has already said, nothing is showing up because of this `for` loop:

```
for (d = 0; d < 7; b++) {
```

You never increment `d` so you stay in this loop *forever* so you never get to display the `JFrame`. You probably want

```
for (d = 0; d < 7; d++) {
```

Aside from that, there are a number of cases of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, the most glaring is this one:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
   for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
      panel.add(pad[x][y]);
   }
}
```

How can you iterate over 9 x 9 buttons when you only have 7 x 7?

Answer (score 5):

Where do you add anything to the ChessSquare JPanel? In other words, where do you see `this.add(...)` or just `add(...)` in the ChessSquare class?

Answer: no where -- you don't add *anything* to it, so nothing shows up.

Comment: at the bottom, i made a loop try to add the botton into panel

Comment: @jdg: right, you add it into ***a*** JPanel, just not ***the*** JPanel. Again, nothing is added to the JPanel that represents the current object, the "`this`". For instance, what is the JPanel named "panel" added to? Nothing. So nothing gets shown. I suggest that you get rid of the panel variable and simply add things to `this`.

Comment: @ hovercraft: i did changed the code but my problem is that not even a window shows up after i java the class file?